# Marketing Cloud Sender Authentication Package configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-domain

We are trying to implement Sender Authentication Package on our Mkt Cloud instance but we are not sure how to go about it. There is close to zero documentation on Mkt Cloud's Help Pages that go about how to configure the tools included in the package.

What we want to do is setup our email subdomain to point to Mkt Cloud's NS servers so we can use our own "From name", after we configure our subdomain with Salesforce's NS server do we have to contact Salesforce se they can complete the setup?

Does anybody else have any experience with SAP configuration? Any advice would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SFMC Support typically handles the SAP configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, this feature is fairly well documented. You should have received an email explaining the process when your account was initially provisioned. Here are a few pages that should help you:

- [Sender Authentication Package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm)
- [Maintaining Your Own DNS Records for Your Sending Domain](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/maintaining_your_own_dns_records_for_your_sending_domain/)
- [Subdomain Delegation Guide](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/subdomain_delegation_guide_for_sender_authentication_package/)

In short, there are four options available for SAP:

1. You select a new domain to represent your brand, example: mycompany-email.com. Salesforce will purchase the domain and handle the entire configuration. There are no technical tasks required from your company. This is the easiest and quickest option.
2. You purchase a domain or use an unused domain you own, example: mycompany.net. This option requires the domain administrator at your company to delegate the domain to Salesforce by adding four nameserver (NS) records to the DNS for the domain.
3. You delegate a subdomain to our nameservers, example: email.mycompany.com. This option requires the domain administrator at your company to create the subdomain and delegate it to us by adding four nameserver (NS) records to the DNS and point them to our nameservers.
4. You host all the DNS records of a domain or subdomain of your choice.

These options are explained in [this quickstart guide](http://senderauth.herokuapp.com/quickstart.php).

It sounds like you need option 2. You will need to refer to the [Subdomain Delegation Guide](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/subdomain_delegation_guide_for_sender_authentication_package/), where you take your chosen subdomain and delegate it to the following servers:

1. ns1.exacttarget.com
2. ns2.exacttarget.com
3. ns3.exacttarget.com
4. ns4.exacttarget.com

Once delegation is complete, you should complete the SAP form at http://senderauth.herokuapp.com so Salesforce can configure your SAP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry I forgot to write back! At the end we are having problems with subdomain delegation as our email service provider does not allow to do this.