# Sender Authentication Package vs sub domain delegation via CNAME

Tags: dkim, dmarc

In another question on this platform, several ways are listed to setup email configurations in DNS:
[Marketing Cloud Sender Authentication Package configuration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130661/marketing-cloud-sender-authentication-package-configuration)

Many clients I work for would like to send emails from their corporate domain, but need to comply with DMARC policies and use a range of suppliers, like salesforce to send emails on their behalf.

The ideal setup would lie in between option 3 and 4, listed in the answer of the mentioned question, with a few challenges:

1. Sub domain delegation delegates too much control to an external
   party for that sub domain.
2. Sub domain delegation let's you send emails from that sub domain, not from the top-level domain, as for the Header From field.
3. Setting up DNS records manually in your Top-Level domain for all suppliers will hit the limits of SPF and create a bunch of DKIM keys throughout your top-level domain (unless you choose to put those in a sub-domain).
4. Setting up DNS records manually would require the client to copy paste public keys and configuration into a web portal in which DNS is managed. Probably spanning multiple support departments between the team managing SaaS applications (such as Salesforce) and DNS management support teams.

For me the ideal setup would be to delegate a sub domain by using CNAME records. This will allow the envelope from to be bounce@sub.domain.com, the header from to be marketing@domain.com and dkim d=sub.domain.com tag.
This setup will require:

1. A dkim CNAME record, i.e. selector1._domainkey.sub.domain.com pointing to a TXT
   record hosted by Salesforce, containing the public key. Preferably 2 CNAME records for the purpose of planned and on-demand key rotation.
2. A CNAME record for bouncehandling and SPF checks: sub.domain.com
   pointing to a subdomain within the Salesforce DNS space, containing
   SPF and MX records, and possibly a webserver hosting the links
   contained in the email.

Is such a setup being actively developed? Will full sub domain delegation (option 3) support sending from the top-level domain as the Header From field?

Thank you,
Rein

References:
https://space.dmarcian.com/how-to-send-dmarc-compliant-email-on-behalf-of-others/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tzink/2015/10/08/manually-hooking-up-dkim-signing-in-office-365/